# .xaml does not exist in Release build

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, exception, release

I have WPF project which builds and runs without problems when in Debug mode.
But when I change it to Release, after running it, I'm getting:

> System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: 'The invocation of the constructor on type 'MyApp.app_Windows.Bootsplash' that matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception.
>   Win32Exception: The system cannot find the file specified

I only know that exception object contains BasicUri:

> {pack://application:,,,/app_Windows/Bootsplash.xaml}

I tried to copy `app_Windows` to release dir, but it won't work (and that's not what I want).

What do I need to do to make it run using Release build?

Comment: Hi K4CZP3R, welcome to Stackoverflow. Can you be more specific about what type of C# project it is?

Comment: @Francis it is a WPF Project